# linq query to get the latest record with default if empty returning list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

The following is a complete code sample

```
static class Program {
    public static List<User> Users = new List<User>();
    public static List<Claim> Claims = new List<Claim>();
    public static List<Valuation> Valuations = new List<Valuation>();
    public static List<Status> Statuses = new List<Status>();
    public static List<StatusHistory> StatusHistories = new List<StatusHistory>();

    static void Main()
    {
        DataSeed();
        var claims = GetClaims(true,0,DateTime.MinValue,DateTime.MaxValue);
        Console.Write(claims);
    }

    static List<ClaimDto> GetClaims(bool active,int userId, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate){
        var claimsInDb = (from status in Program.Statuses
                                join statusHistory in Program.StatusHistories on status.Id equals statusHistory.StatusId
                                join claim in Program.Claims on statusHistory.ClaimId equals claim.Id
                                join valuation in Program.Valuations on claim.ActiveEvaluationId equals valuation.Id
                                join user in Program.Users on claim.AssignedTo equals user.Id into joined
                                from joinedUser in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                      where status.Active & active
                                          ? status.Name != "Complete"
                                          : status.Name == "Complete"
                                            & statusHistory.CreatedDt > fromDate & statusHistory.CreatedDt < toDate
                                            & userId == 0
                                              ? joinedUser.Id != -1
                                              : joinedUser.Id == userId

                                      group new ClaimDto
                                    {
                                        Id = claim.Id,
                                        AssignedToUserFullName = joinedUser.FullName,
                                        CreatedDt = claim.CreatedDt,
                                        Status = status.Name,
                                        Version = valuation.Version
                                    } 
                                    by new
                                    {
                                        claim.Id
                                    }
                                into grouped

                                //where  active
                                //    ? grouped.Key.status.Name != "Complete"
                                //    : grouped.Key.status.Name == "Complete"
                                //      & grouped.Key.statusHistory.CreatedDt > fromDate& grouped.Key.statusHistory.CreatedDt < toDate
                                //      & userId == 0 
                                //        ? grouped.Key.joinedUser.Id != 0
                                //          : grouped.Key.joinedUser.Id == userId

                                //orderby grouped.Key.statusHistory.CreatedDt descending 

                                select grouped.FirstOrDefault()
                            ).ToList();
        return claimsInDb;
    }

    static void DataSeed(){
    //dataSeed
        Users.Add(new User
        {
            Id = 1,
            FullName = "Dmitry Post",
        });

        Claims.AddRange(new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim
            {
                Id = 1,
                AssignedTo = 1,
                CreatedDt = DateTime.Now,
                ActiveEvaluationId = 1
            },
            new Claim
            {
                Id = 2,
                AssignedTo = 1,
                CreatedDt = DateTime.Now,
                ActiveEvaluationId = 2
            }
        });

        Valuations.AddRange(new List<Valuation>
        {
            new Valuation
            {
                Id = 1,
                Version = 1,
                ClaimId = 1
            },
            new Valuation
            {
                Id = 2,
                Version = 1,
                ClaimId = 2
            }
        });

        Statuses.AddRange(new List<Status>
        {
            new Status
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "New",
                Active = true,              
            },
            new Status
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "In Progress",
                Active = true,
            },
            new Status
            {
                Id = 3,
                Name = "Complete",
                Active = true,
            }
        });

        StatusHistories.AddRange(new List<StatusHistory>
        {
            new StatusHistory
            {
                Id = 1,
                ClaimId = 1,
                CreatedDt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10),
                StatusId = 1
            },
            new StatusHistory
            {
                Id = 2,
                ClaimId = 1,
                CreatedDt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                StatusId = 2
            },
            new StatusHistory
            {
                Id = 3,
                ClaimId = 2,
                CreatedDt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10),
                StatusId = 1
            },
            new StatusHistory
            {
                Id = 4,
                ClaimId = 2,
                CreatedDt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-9),
                StatusId = 2
            },
            new StatusHistory
            {
                Id = 5,
                ClaimId = 2,
                CreatedDt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-8),
                StatusId = 3
            },
        });
    }
}
//objects
class ClaimDto{
public int Id {get;set;}
public DateTime CreatedDt {get;set;}
public string Status {get;set;}
public int Version {get;set;}
public string AssignedToUserFullName {get;set;}
}

class Status{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public bool Active {get;set;}
}

class StatusHistory{
public int Id {get;set;}
public int StatusId {get;set;}
public int ClaimId {get;set;}
public DateTime CreatedDt {get;set;}
}

class Claim{
public int Id {get;set;}
public int ActiveEvaluationId {get;set;}
public DateTime CreatedDt {get;set;}
public int AssignedTo {get;set;}
}

class Valuation{
public int Id {get;set;}
public int Version {get;set;}
public int ClaimId {get;set;}
}

class User{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string FullName {get;set;}
}
```

My desired result is when active = true, userId = 0, fromDate = DateTime.MinValue, toDate = DateTime.MaxValue

To return 1 Record:
One because there is one claim that has status history of complete.

When active = false, userId = 0, fromDate = DateTime.MinValue, toDate = DateTime.MaxValue

To return 1 Record:
One because there is one claim that has no status histories of complete.

When active = false, userId = 1, fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5), toDate = DateTime.MaxValue

To return 1 Record:
One because the first claims latest status history CreateDt is within the date range and the claim is assigned to user with that Id

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding property to Valuation class for the currentStatusHistory id and adjusting the join accordingly.

```
static class Program {
    public static List<User> Users = new List<User>();
    public static List<Claim> Claims = new List<Claim>();
    public static List<Valuation> Valuations = new List<Valuation>();
    public static List<Status> Statuses = new List<Status>();
    public static List<StatusHistory> StatusHistories = new List<StatusHistory>();

    static void Main()
    {
        DataSeed();
        var claims = GetClaims(true,0,DateTime.MinValue,DateTime.MaxValue);
        Console.Write(claims);
    }

    static List<ClaimDto> GetClaims(bool active,int userId, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate){
        var claimsInDb = (from status in Program.Statuses
                                join statusHistory in context.StatusHistories on status.StatusId equals statusHistory.StatusId
                                join valuation in context.Valuations on statusHistory.StatusHistoryId equals valuation.StatusHistoryId
                                join claim in context.Claims on statusHistory.ClaimId equals claim.ClaimId
                                join user in context.Users on claim.AssignedTo equals user.UserId into joined
                                from joinedUser in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                      where status.Active & active
                                          ? status.Name != "Complete"
                                          : status.Name == "Complete"
                                            & statusHistory.CreatedDt > fromDate & statusHistory.CreatedDt < toDate
                                            & userId == 0
                                              ? joinedUser.Id != -1
                                              : joinedUser.Id == userId

                                      group new ClaimDto
                                    {
                                        Id = claim.Id,
                                        AssignedToUserFullName = joinedUser.FullName,
                                        CreatedDt = claim.CreatedDt,
                                        Status = status.Name,
                                        Version = valuation.Version
                                    } 
                                    by new
                                    {
                                        claim.Id
                                    }
                                into grouped


                                select grouped.FirstOrDefault()
                            ).ToList();
        return claimsInDb;
    }

    static void DataSeed(){
    //dataSeed
        Users.Add(new User
        {
            Id = 1,
            FullName = "Dmitry Post",
        });

        Claims.AddRange(new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim
            {
                Id = 1,
                AssignedTo = 1,
                CreatedDt = DateTime.Now,
                ActiveEvaluationId = 1
            },
            new Claim
            {
                Id = 2,
                AssignedTo = 1,
                CreatedDt = DateTime.Now,
                ActiveEvaluationId = 2
            }
        });

        Valuations.AddRange(new List<Valuation>
        {
            new Valuation
            {
                Id = 1,
                Version = 1,
                ClaimId = 1,
                StatusHistoryId = 2,
            },
            new Valuation
            {
                Id = 2,
                Version = 1,
                ClaimId = 2,
                StatusHistoryId = 5,
            }
        });

        Statuses.AddRange(new List<Status>
        {
            new Status
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "New",
                Active = true,              
            },
            new Status
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "In Progress",
                Active = true,
            },
            new Status
            {
                Id = 3,
                Name = "Complete",
                Active = true,
            }
        });

        StatusHistories.AddRange(new List<StatusHistory>
        {
            new StatusHistory
            {
                Id = 1,
                ClaimId = 1,
                CreatedDt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10),
                StatusId = 1
            },
            new StatusHistory
            {
                Id = 2,
                ClaimId = 1,
                CreatedDt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                StatusId = 2
            },
            new StatusHistory
            {
                Id = 3,
                ClaimId = 2,
                CreatedDt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10),
                StatusId = 1
            },
            new StatusHistory
            {
                Id = 4,
                ClaimId = 2,
                CreatedDt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-9),
                StatusId = 2
            },
            new StatusHistory
            {
                Id = 5,
                ClaimId = 2,
                CreatedDt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-8),
                StatusId = 3
            },
        });
    }
}
//objects
class ClaimDto{
public int Id {get;set;}
public DateTime CreatedDt {get;set;}
public string Status {get;set;}
public int Version {get;set;}
public string AssignedToUserFullName {get;set;}
}

class Status{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public bool Active {get;set;}
}

class StatusHistory{
public int Id {get;set;}
public int StatusId {get;set;}
public int ClaimId {get;set;}
public DateTime CreatedDt {get;set;}
}

class Claim{
public int Id {get;set;}
public int ActiveEvaluationId {get;set;}
public DateTime CreatedDt {get;set;}
public int AssignedTo {get;set;}
}

class Valuation{
public int Id {get;set;}
public int Version {get;set;}
public int ClaimId {get;set;}
public int StatusHistoryId {get;set;}
}

class User{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string FullName {get;set;}
}
```